# Vista: Making Mastered the default burning setting

Tags: windows-vista, burning, dvd-burning, udf, mastering

I'm currently backing off a ton of data onto DVDs, but I've already lost one DVD because I forgot to select the hidden option of "Mastered" before I pressed "next". Is there a way to make this the default setting?

I don't want to have to install burning software, and I'm never going to use the "Live Files System".

Thanks for any help.

[image]